# How to add dynamic value in Map in Dart?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, collections

I have a dynamic UI which maybe dropdown or textField!

I need to prepare map to send to backend. Below is map format that i need to prepare from the dynamic UI,

```
Map temp;

  temp = {
    "receiver": {
      "Bank": {"accounnt": '123'},
    }
  };
  if(temp['receiver']['school'] == null){
    temp['receiver']['school'] = '12';
  }
```

But where I am getting error when I am trying to add  `temp['receiver']['school'] = '12';`. The error states that, `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' of 'value.'`

I want to create a map in below format,

```
  "receiver": {
    "bank_account": {
      "swift_bic": "XXX",
      "account_number": "225225"
    },
    "reason_for_sending": "Family"
  }
 


 Error image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yg2t.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
void main() {
 Map<String,Map<String,dynamic>> temp;

  temp = {
    "receiver": {
      "Bank": {"accounnt": '123'}
    }
  };
  if(temp['receiver']!['school'] == null){
    temp['receiver']!['school'] = '12';
  }
  print(temp);
}
```

Comment: Great! it works like a charm!  But why do we need to do this?  if we didn't mention then it should take this as dynamic right?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but, nested maps can get a bit tricky because the compiler might not be able to assign a correct type during runtime. That is what i am thinking is happening